# Capacitor : Can't build with push-notifications plulgin

Tags: java, android, firebase, vue.js, capacitor

I am trying to use the capacitor push notifications plugin in a quasar project. So I followed [this](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/push-notifications-firebase) tutorial.

But when building with the command : `quasar build -m capacitor -T android` outputs this error (quasar project) :

```
> Task :capacitor-push-notifications:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':capacitor-push-notifications:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.
> invalid source release: 11
```

I'm not sure if the error comes from the plugin itself or if I did something wrong during the installation. I tried redoing the tutorial from the beginning but I got the same error.

Note :

Before installing this plugin, everything was working correctly when building.

Dev with `quasar dev` on web still works though but with this error : `Error: "PushNotifications" plugin is not implemented on web`

And `quasar dev` for android gives this output :

```
src-capacitor/node_modules/@capacitor/push-notifications/android/src/main/java/com/capacitorjs/plugins/pushnotifications/PushNotificationsPlugin.java:3: error: package android.app does not exist import android.app.Notification;
```

Comment: Version 4.0.0 of the plugins are meant to be used with capacitor 4 and I was using capacitor 3. I downgraded the module to the closest 1.x.x version and it now works

Answer (score 0):

First of all. To test in dev mode and use capacitor, i think it is best to use

quasar dev -m capacitor -T android

So to install capacitor plugins and to test them you must install them inside src-capacitor.

To use capacitor plugins olso in normal dev mode you must install the plugin olso in the root folder of the quasar project.

Check your package.json inside src-capacitor

If you installed the 4.x version of the notification plugin you get this error.

Remove the package inside src-capacitor

```
npm remove @capacitor/push-notifications 

npx cap sync
```

and then reinstall by specifing the 1.0.9 version

```
npm install @capacitor/push-notifications@1.0.9

npx cap sync
```

I had the same error.
The concept can be applied to many plugins.

StatusBar plugin also get similar error by installing the last update.